# How to left align and right align in the same line in iTextSharp?

Tags: itext

In CSS, we can have two divs (each of width 50%) in the same line, and tell the left div to float left and the right div to float right. Is this possible in iTextSharp? I ask because I need to format my pdf header such that the article title and the page number both appear in the same line, but the article title is left aligned, and the page number is right aligned like so:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create a 2-cell table for your header?

Comment: Thanks, and set the table width to be 100%, then left-align the left cell and right-align the right cell in the row? I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what i meant!

Comment: I tried it and it works out pretty well. Thanks. I've had a mindset of "tables are not good for layout in html", but didn't realize that I am actually dealing with PDF.

Comment: You might want to post your solution as an answer then. You can even accept it, it's explicitly [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here on SO.

Comment: Can you share your answer?